# Angularjs - ng-click function vs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I can't decide which method to use in following case. I'm trying to alert when clicking on buttons. I can do this using 2 methods. Which is the best practice and please tell me why?

**Method 1**

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <button alert>directive</button>
</div>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app
  .directive('alert', function(){
    return {

      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            element.on('click', function(){
          alert('clicked');
        })
      }

    }
  })
```

**Method 2**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button ng-click="go()">ng-click</button>  
</div>
```

---

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.go = function() {
    alert('clicked');
  }
}]);
```

Thank you,
Rushan

Comment: Directives are self contained objects including both template and logic. If you are planning to run that code across a lot of views with different controllers a directive is the way to go. If you are planning use it only in a view with a single controller attached it has no point

Comment: @vkt: is it ok to use directive on all  cases. I mean whether it's a single use or multiple?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let me explain it to you using example.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
        <button ng-click="showAlert('hello')">Fist</button>
        <button ng-click="showConsole('hello')">for Fist one only</button>
        <button show-alert="first using directive">Fist with directive</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
        <button ng-click="showAlert('hello second')">Second</button>
        <button show-alert="first using directive">Second With directive</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl3">
        <button ng-click="showAlert('hello third')">Third</button>
        <button show-alert="third using directive">third with directive</button>
    </div>
 </div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp',[]);

myApp
    .controller('MyCtrl1', function ($scope) {
        $scope.showAlert = function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        };
        $scope.showConsole = function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        };
    })
    .controller('MyCtrl2', function ($scope) {
        $scope.showAlert = function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        };

    })
    .controller('MyCtrl3', function ($scope) {
        $scope.showAlert = function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        };        
    })
    .directive('showAlert', function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, ele, attr){
                var eventName = attr.evetName || 'click';
                var mas = attr.showAlert || 'just alert';
                ele.on(eventName, function(){
                   alert(mas); 
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

[JsFiddleLink](http://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/w9w65tk7/1/)

As you can see in the example `show-alert="[MSG]"` was able to reduce code replication compared to directly using `$scope.showAlert` in each controller. so in this case creating directive was better.

But, in case of `$scope.showConsole` was used only once, we are not reusing it anywhere. so its fine to use it directly inside controller.

Even though. you can also create directive for `showConsole` functionality, if you feel like in future it will be used somewhere else also. its totally fine. this decisions totally depends on the what use-case you have.

Answer (score 2):

If all elements have to run the same function on click event, making it a directive is a good idea. Otherwise use ngClick. Creating a directive and then passing a click handler function is reimplemeting the same thing.